# Firefox extension to view/browse history in a 'better' way

Tags: windows, firefox

Google Chrome has a handy extension which allows you to browse through your history in a better way: [Better History](http://better-history.com/) ([Chrome Web Store page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-history/obciceimmggglbmelaidpjlmodcebijb)).

Its main features are:

- Filter your browser history by day
- Filter your browser history by hour
- Search history with regular expressions (RegEx)
- And, last but not least, view your history in a more appeasing interface (compared to the default `chrome://history` page)

Unfortunately, Firefox's history manager lacks most of these features, and it just looks plain ugly (IMHO). In addition, having to open a new window to view the full browser history is just plain counter-productive; I'd prefer to view my history in a tab, just like Google Chrome (and Chromium browsers in general).

So, I basically want an extension similar to "Better History", but for Mozilla Firefox. At the very least I want to be able to view my history in a tab (I already tried `about:history`, doesn't work); the other features are optional, but desired.

---

A screenshot of the Chrome extension taken from the extension's website (to give non-Chrome users an idea of what I'm talking about):

[image: Better History]

Comment: better-history link down....

Answer (score 1):

[Norwell History addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/norwell/)

- shows the history in a tab
- shows hours and minutes
- you can set filters (see image below)
- searching a bit like Regex, plus 'or' and 'allinurl:', 'allintitle:' operators (see image)

Filters: to apply the filters you have to click the search button ([fully-sized image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5caj.png))
[image: filters]

Searching
[image: searching]

Comment: While that is the best I could have come up with as well, it's not nearly as good looking... also it's not working with the most recent version of Firefox anymore (Quantum) - On the other hand Chrome is soo resource hungry, so stuck between a rock and a hard place...

Comment: right there with you julix! This fork I found on reddit might work https://www.reddit.com/r/XUL_for_Quantum_Dev/comments/97exmv/norwell_history_tools/